# How move View alongside DrawerLayout's content whit the same Z

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

I have my main view with 3 `Button`s in a vertical `LinearLayout` on top right of the screen. Each button shows some `Fragment` that is hosted inside a `DrawerLayout`. Like this:

[image]

When I click any button, I want the DrawerLayout to be shown from the right and this button to be translated alongside it. Like this:

[image]

I have managed to move the `Button` with the drawer but my problem is that the drawers's shadow affects the button as well. I want it to be so bright as the drawer's content (same hight) but I also want the other buttons to remain behind the drawer.

This is my **activity_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

        <LinearLayout ... >
            <ImageButton ... />
            <ImageButton ... />
            <ImageButton ... />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_secondary_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            tools:context="..."/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With the buttons inside `DrawerLayout`, the drawer moves above them but the one that's being translated gets dark.

On the other hand if I put the buttons outside DrawerLayout, the button that moves looks all right but the drawer is below the other buttons. Like:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid DrawerLayout's shadow to affect a particular view? Or perhaps to cancel it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` applies that shadow - the scrim - to its child `View`s in its `drawChild()` method. It determines which children to apply it to by checking that a given child is not a drawer `View`. It ultimately does this by checking the `gravity` of the child's `LayoutParams`.

Knowing this, we can create a custom `DrawerLayout` subclass to override `drawChild()`, and temporarily change the `gravity` on the child that we don't want the scrim applied to. Since no layout is happening during the draw, this won't affect the actual placement of the `View`.

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    private int noScrimId;

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Get the ID for the no-scrim View.
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomDrawerLayout);
        noScrimId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomDrawerLayout_noScrimView, View.NO_ID);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        // Is this the child we want?
        final boolean isNoScrimView = child.getId() == noScrimId;

        // If yes, temporarily tag it as a drawer.
        if (isNoScrimView) {
            ((LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        }

        // Let the super class do the draw, and save the return.
        final boolean res = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);

        // Reset the gravity if we changed it.
        if (isNoScrimView) {
            ((LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

This example uses a custom attribute so that the "no-scrim" `View` can be specified in the layout. If you don't want to use that attribute, you can remove the `TypedArray` processing from the constructor, and just hardcode an ID. If you do want to use the custom attribute, you need to define it in your project, which you can do by sticking the following file in the `values/` folder, or adding to the one that might already be there.

`attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomDrawerLayout">
        <attr name="noScrimView" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`CustomDrawerLayout` is a drop-in replacement, and you can use it in your layouts just like you would the regular class. For example, if your `ImageButton`s' `LinearLayout` has the ID `button_menu`:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.CustomDrawerLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:noScrimView="@+id/button_menu">
```

---

Please note that if you should happen to set a drawer `View` as the `noScrimView`, you're gonna have a bad time. Also, the `noScrimView` must be a direct child of the `DrawerLayout`, as the scrim effect is applied only to those.

For simplicity's sake, I've omitted any checks from the sample, but if you wish to include some, doing them in the `onMeasure()` method would be in line with how `DrawerLayout` handles its own checks.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final View v = findViewById(noScrimId);
    if (v != null) {
        if (!(v.getLayoutParams() instanceof LayoutParams)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("noScrimView must be a child of DrawerLayout");
        }
        if (((LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams()).gravity != Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("noScrimView cannot be a drawer View");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (noScrimId != View.NO_ID) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "noScrimView not found");
        }
    }
}
```